# What meaning does とこ have in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> **とこ**の状況で思っちゃう僕はちょっとおかしいのか。

I'm not sure how to interpret this sentence. What function is とこ serving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should parse it as:

> と、この状況で思っちゃう僕は・・・

The と is the quotative particle.